# How to draw a figure of taxonomy in tikz or similars

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the best way to draw a taxonomy in the style of
 the following figure?

[image: Taxonomy]

Comment: Maybe something from http://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/ could be useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}
\begin{document}
% starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341454/121799
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    font=\sffamily,
    line width=1pt,
    draw,
    child anchor=north,
    parent anchor=south,
    grow=south,
    align=center,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path[line width=1pt, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor)  |- ([yshift=4pt].child anchor) -- (.child anchor) \forestoption{edge label};
    },
  },
  s sep+=20pt,
  [1 Clustering Ensemble\\ Approaches,drop shadow,
  fill=white,double=white,
    [2.1 Generative\\ Mechanism,double=white 
     [3.1 Different\\ Algorithms]
     [,phantom]
     [3.2 Single\\ Algorithms
     [4.1 Different built--in\\ initialization]
     [~\\~,opacity=0,name=phantom1
      [4.3 Different subsets\\ of features]
      [~\\~,opacity=0,name=phantom2
       [4.5 Different subsets\\ of objects]
      ]
      [4.4 Projecting data\\ onto different subspaces]
      ]
     [4.2 Different\\ parameters]
     ]
    ]
    [2.2 Consensus\\ Function,double=white
     [3.3 Information Theory\\ Approach]
     [~\\~,opacity=0,name=phantom3
      [3.5 Voting approach]
      [~,opacity=0,name=phantom4
       [3.7 Hypergraph\\ methods]
      ]
      [3.6 Mixture Model (EM)]
      ]
     [3.4 Co--association\\ based approach]
     ]
   ]
  \begin{scope}[line width=1pt]
   \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
   {\draw (phantom\X.north) -- (phantom\X.south);}
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider using the `edges` library for this style of branching. It integrates much better with other options.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version using the Forest `edges` library, which makes these kinds of trees a lot easier. I've shamelessly stolen [marmot's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436172/) to avoid typing it all out, but I've altered the structure of the tree a bit to simplify things and relied on Forest options rather than manual spacing, to help ensure consistency and make the code both simpler and more flexible.

I've also tweaked the style as I wasn't keen on the double lines or the squared corners after I'd finished, and found I preferred a subtler shadow for the root, with a very slight shading for all nodes. Obviously, these changes are independent of the Forest code itself, so you can easily get that pushy shadow, hard edges and doubled lines if you prefer them. (In some moods, I might prefer them - but not in this one, apparently.)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
% addaswyd o ateb marmot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436172/
% starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341454/121799
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={font=\sffamily, rounded corners, top color=gray!5, bottom color=gray!10, edge+={darkgray, line width=1pt}, draw=darkgray, align=center, anchor=children},
  before packing={where n children=3{calign child=2, calign=child edge}{}},
  before typesetting nodes={where content={}{coordinate}{}},
  where level<=1{line width=2pt}{line width=1pt},
  [1 Clustering Ensemble\\Approaches, blur shadow
    [2.1 Generative\\Mechanism
     [3.1 Different\\Algorithms]
     [3.2 Single\\Algorithms
        [4.1 Different built--in\\initialization]
        [
          [4.3 Different subsets\\of features]
          [
            [4.5 Different subsets\\of objects]
          ]
          [4.4 Projecting data\\onto different subspaces]
        ]
        [4.2 Different\\parameters]
      ]
    ]
    [2.2 Consensus\\Function
      [3.3 Information Theory\\Approach]
      [
        [3.5 Voting approach]
        [
          [3.7 Hypergraph\\methods]
        ]
        [3.6 Mixture Model (EM)]
      ]
      [3.4 Co--association\\based approach]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest tree - simpler, but more automatised, consistent and flexible code with stylistic variations]